# Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "createCollection"' error while using pre method before saving schema

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

**Image link of the code**

**I have tried many things but it didn't work my mongoose version 8^**
I've created a schema and as usual i wanted to save password with pre built in method in mongoose with typescript but its giving me error in save event handler. I've tried with many things but it remains same , i tried to using true parameter as like we used in old mongoose version also not worked

```
 import { NextFunction } from "express";
import mongoose, { Document, Model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
const emailRegexPatters: RegExp = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;

export interface IUser extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  avatar: {
    public_id: string;
    url: string;
  };
  role: string;
  isVerified: boolean;
  courses: Array<{ courseId: string }>;
  comparePassword: (password: string) => Promise<boolean>;
}

const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your name"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your email"],
      validate: {
        validator: function (value: string) {
          return emailRegexPatters.test(value);
        },
        message: "Please enter a valid email!",
      },
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "please enter a password"],
      minlength: [6, "Password must be at least 6 characters!"],
      select: false,
    },
    avatar: {
      public_id: String,
      url: String,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "user",
    },
    isVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    courses: [
      {
        courseId: String,
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// hash password


userSchema.pre<IUser>("save",async function (next: NextFunction) {
  if (!this.isModified("password") || this.isNew) {
    // If the password is not modified or a new user is being created, skip hashing
    return next();
  }
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (enteredPassword: string) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

const userModel: Model<IUser> = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default userModel;
```